# Unable to right click on web page

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, debugging

I use Chrome and I have weird behaviour on a site I'm building:

I'm not able to right click anywhere on the page so I assume it's code related (I can right click on other windows).

Anybody ever encountered a similar issue?

Edit: Looks like the issue may lie with me.

Comment: working fine on chrome & fire fox. Right click is firing

Comment: Works for me, Chrome Version 39.0.2171.95 m

Comment: i think this is your browser specific issue

Comment: Have you tried restarting your browser?

Answer (score 0):

download this https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/righttoclick/ for mozilla

and this https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/enable-right-click/hhojmcideegachlhfgfdhailpfhgknjm for chrome

then right click to extract source code and get what you want